# WiFi getSSID() always returns "<unknown ssid>"

Tags: java, android, wifi

This question has already been asked by many people, but the solution that worked for them is not working for me.  I have tested on Android 8.1 and Android 9.0 and cannot get the name of the SSID.

Broadcast receiver for getting WiFi state changes:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if(intent.getAction().equals(WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION) ||
                intent.getAction().equals(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION) ||
                intent.getAction().equals(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION) ||
                intent.getAction().equals(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION) ||
                intent.getAction().equals(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION)) {
            setWifiIndicator();
        }
    }
};
```

The receiver is registered `onCreate` and unregistered in `onDestroy`, which I think is proper, and I'm seeing the log lines when the receiver is called.

in `onCreate`:

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction(ScannerService.ACTION_READ_SCANNER);
intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION);
intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
intentFilter.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
registerReceiver(mReceiver, intentFilter);
setWifiIndicator();
```

`setWifiIndicator` is implemented thusly:

```
private void setWifiIndicator() {
    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    //getApplicationContext solves memory leak issues prior to Android N (must use Application Context to get wifi system service.
    WifiManager wifiMgr = (WifiManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    ImageView wifiIndicator = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.wifi_indicator);
    TextView wifiSSID = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.wifi_ssid);

    try {
        if (wifiMgr != null) {
            if (wifiMgr.isWifiEnabled()) {
                //wifi is enabled.  toggle on wifi indicator.
                wifiIndicator.setImageResource(R.drawable.wifi_indicator);
                String ssid = wifiMgr.getConnectionInfo().getSSID();
                if (ssid != null) {
                    Log.v(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "SSID: " + ssid + "  Supplicant State: " + info.getSupplicantState());
                    wifiSSID.setText(ssid);
                }
            } else {
                //wifi is disabled.  toggle off wifi indicator.
                wifiSSID.setText("");

                //check for 3G
                NetworkInfo mobileInfo = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
                if (mobileInfo != null && mobileInfo.getState().equals(NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)) {
                    wifiIndicator.setImageResource(R.drawable.cellular_indicator);
                } else {
                    wifiIndicator.setImageResource(R.drawable.down_indicator);
                }
            }
        } else {
            //check for 3G
            NetworkInfo mobileInfo = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
            if (mobileInfo != null && mobileInfo.getState().equals(NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)) {
                wifiIndicator.setImageResource(R.drawable.cellular_indicator);
            } else {
                wifiIndicator.setImageResource(R.drawable.down_indicator);
            }
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        //catching anything thrown in this block just so it doesn't crash the program unnecessarily
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My app already had permission for `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` but I aslo added `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` just in case.  `getSSID()` is till returning `<unknown ssid>`.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
```

Perhaps it has to do with compile target SDK?  I'm really clueless here.

gradle file:

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.noneofyour.business"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 59
        versionName "1.44"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation files('libs/android.jar')
}
```

Comment: Could you test with the GPS on please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried to check if `getSupplicantState()` is `COMPLETED`?

```
if(wifiInfo.getSupplicantState() == SupplicantState.COMPLETED){
    String ssid = wifiInfo.getSSID();
    wifiSSID.setText(ssid);
}
```

Also, have you asked for this before running the `BroadcastReceiver` or even inside you can do it:

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, LOCATION);
} else {
    setWifiIndicator();
}
```

Comment: The solution involved your second code snippet. I was avoiding the compatibility libraries, and it seems that even though the permission is set in the AndriodManifest.xml file, the permission is not actually granted for some reason?  I would like to have the permission granted without using compatibility libraries. This seems like a bug. This does solve the problem, but it forces the user to respond to a prompt and forces me to use compatibility libraries. Not desired behavior at all.

Comment: After a bit of research, I was able to find a way to do this without using the compatibility library to check for permissions. I didn't realize that all permissions were disabled by default when the app is installed. This makes little sense to me, but there you have it. The answer was found in this article:
https://help.kustom.rocks/i1571-ssid-shows-unknown-ssid-after-updating-to-android-8-1-oreo

Comment: That's why you have to `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions` to activate them :D

Answer (score 19):

Wi-Fi Permissions

Android 8.0 and Android 8.1:

A successful call to WifiManager.getScanResults() requires any one of the following permissions:

•   ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
•   ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
•   CHANGE_WIFI_STATE

If the calling app does not have any of these permissions, the call fails with a SecurityException.

Android 9:

A successful call to WifiManager.startScan() requires all of the following conditions to be met:

•   Your app has the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permission.
•   Your app has the CHANGE_WIFI_STATE permission.
•   Location services are enabled on the device (under Settings > Location).

Android 10 (API level 29) and higher:

A successful call to WifiManager.startScan() requires all of the following conditions to be met:

•   If your app is targeting Android 10 (API level 29) SDK or higher, your app has the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.

•   If your app is targeting SDK lower than Android 10 (API level 29), your app has the ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.

•   Your app has the CHANGE_WIFI_STATE permission.

•   Location services are enabled on the device (under Settings > Location).

And Request User level permission to achieve

See this link for more information: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-scan#wifi-scan-permissions

XAMARIN FORMS Code Change:

```
if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.O){
status = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Location);
if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
{   
var results = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(new[] { Permission.Location });
status = results[Permission.Location];
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for details depending on version, especially the need to implement Request User level permission for ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

Comment: Switching on Location Services !!!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to all answers, if your device's GPS is disabled, you may be faced with  issue.

So, please enable your gps from the settings.

Answer (score 0):

Go to setting manually and provide location access to your app since it is "NOT ALLOWED" by default

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).